# SenchaTouch: how can i pass parameters from a list to another?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new to SenchaTouch. I have a list and when I tap on an item I would like to pass the id clicked to the next list. How can I do this?

Here is my code for tap item:

```
MyApp.views.list.on("itemtap",function(dataView,index,item,e){
    var id=dataView.store.getAt(index).data.id;
    MyApp.views.viewport.setActiveItem('chartContainer',{ type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
};
```

How can I pass `id` to `chartContainer` and how can it handle?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the xtype of the new List use the constructor so you can do something like this:

```
var id=dataView.store.getAt(index).data.id;
var chartContainer = new MyApp.views.ChartContainer();
chartContainer.id = id;
MyApp.views.viewport.setActiveItem(chartContainer,{ type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
```

now inside you ChartContainer instance you can use:

```
this.id
```

notice that on the setActiveItem, chartContainer does not have quotes.